# Wordpress auto adding <a> tags

Tags: wordpress

I would like to put a  tag outside of a div (I know, it's bad)

But when i'm doing it, Wordpress adds SO many links :

Before :

```
</div>
<h2>- wcwcwxcwxc -</h2>
<div class="container-formation">
<div class="block_formation white_background">
<p class="p">wxcwxcwxcwxc</p>

</div>
<div class="block_formation white_background">
<p class="p">wxcwxcwxcwxc</p>

</div>
<div class="block_formation white_background">
<p class="p">wxcwxcwxcwxc</p>

</div>
<div class="block_formation white_background">
<p class="p">wwxcwxcwxcwxc</p>

</div>
<a href="qsdfjnsdfkjsfsjdfbdsoif">
<div class="block_formation white_background">
<p class="p">wxcwxcwxcwxc</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

After :

```
</div>
<h2>- wcwcwxcwxc -</h2>
<div class="container-formation">
<div class="block_formation white_background">
<p class="p">wxcwxcwxcwxc</p>

</div>
<div class="block_formation white_background">
<p class="p">wxcwxcwxcwxc</p>

</div>
<div class="block_formation white_background">
<p class="p">wxcwxcwxcwxc</p>

</div>
<div class="block_formation white_background">
<p class="p">wwxcwxcwxcwxc</p>

</div>
<a href="qsdfjnsdfkjsfsjdfbdsoif"></a>

<a href="qsdfjnsdfkjsfsjdfbdsoif"></a>

<a href="qsdfjnsdfkjsfsjdfbdsoif">
<div class="block_formation white_background">
<p class="p">wxcwxcwxcwxc</p>
</div>
</a><a href="qsdfjnsdfkjsfsjdfbdsoif"></a><a href="qsdfjnsdfkjsfsjdfbdsoif"></a>
</div>
```

Everytime I go back on this page, 3  links appeared. It never ends !

I'm totally lost with it. 
Can someone help me please ?

I already put :

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

In my funtions.php

Comment: I'm just querying where the `</div>` at the start of your before sample came from?

Comment: I would try to write it without linebreaks in the code

Comment: Is there any other plugin or code that's adding `wpautop` to `the_content()`?

Comment: Also are you using the visual editor or code editor? Try using the code editor, along with the `remove_filter` functions you mention, and save the page, then look.

Comment: No there isn't !